# How can I reset or empty req.user in a node passport app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js

I'm trying to authenticate a user when logging in to website.  Upon login, the username and password get sent to a post route from an ajax request on the client side.  The problem is that there is an old userID attached to req.user._id that I cannot remove.  This old userID continues to authenticate any user I try.

This is my passport settings on the server:

```js
var passport = require('passport');
var BasicStrategy = require('passport-http').BasicStrategy;

var strategy = new BasicStrategy(function(username, password, callback) {
    User.findOne({
        username: username
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }

        if (!user) {
            return callback(null, false, {
                message: 'Incorrect username.'
            });
        }

        user.validatePassword(password, function(err, isValid) {
            if (err) {
                return callback(err);
            }

            if (!isValid) {
                return callback(null, false, {
                    message: 'Incorrect password.'
                });
            }
            return callback(null, user);
        });
    });
});

passport.use(strategy);
app.use(passport.initialize());
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

This is my route:

```js
app.post('/authenticate', passport.authenticate('basic', { session: false }), function(req, res) {

        console.log("req.user:", req.user);
        var id = req.user._id;
        res.json({
            message: 'You have been authenticated',
            userID: id
        });
    });
```

On the client side, I am sending a POST request like this:

```js
function getLogin(loginObject) {

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/authenticate",
            dataType : "json",
            data: { username: loginObject.username, password: loginObject.password }
        })
        .done(function(result) {
            console.log("Authenticated");
            loginUserID = result.userID;
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
};
```

This is a screenshot of my terminal showing the userID that won't delete:

```js
req.user: { _id: 588a834c08c038342e420568,
  username: 'mm',
  password: '$2a$10$Khp1wUkHvLLn6ZVBNlLqM.Mtio0ZZ4dznGPQs0ECqf.snhUl44OxK',
  __v: 0 }
```

From my understanding, the req.user._id is created as soon as the username and password get's authenticated.  So I cannot understand what is holding on to this userID.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: Since you've disabled sessions, I don't think you need the serializeUser and deserializeUser methods. Also note that, in the code above code, you refer to `req.user._id` even though your serializer is looking for `user.id`. Try just deleting those methods.

Comment: @SylonZero, thanks for helping out.  I removed both of the methods that you mentioned, but still having the same issue.  The first user that I login with remains in session.  One other thing that I just noticed, when I empty my database, then register a new user, then try to login, I immediately get another login popup form, looks like it's coming from the browser.  And it says, "localhost:8080 requires a username and password".  Whatever I enter here, stays in session.  I don't know what is making this second popup window appear.

Comment: Is your node http listener running on port 8080? That pop up window might be your Passport auth in action if you are serving the rest of your pages via 8080...

Comment: Yes, it's listening on 8080.  I just tried listening to port 3000, but I still see the popup window.

Comment: No, you can use any port number that works with your dev machine. The pop up with 8080 is your basic auth via Passport. It sounds like it's working. Try closing all your browser windows and use a Chrome incognito window to see if you can enter a different username for testing. Remember to close ALL incognito instances between tests.